# issue upgrading to new angular/cli

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I attempted to upgrade from Angular-cli beta.28 following instructions here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc.0-update to the latest angular/cli due to a href overwrite bug...

Now when I run ng --version (to see what version I am on), I get the following error...How do I fix this? and if this is expected behavior, How due I determine my version now?  The application appears to work well and the overwrite bug is fixed...

> npm --version
>   4.3.0 PS C:\Users\tpfield\git\ode\ode-client> ng --version ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
>   file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
>   path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + ng --version
>   + ~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Did the install/update run without a ton of errors? Did you run the install/update as admin or root?

Comment: The application appears to be working ok and the href overwrite bug is fixed...I didn't run as root, let me try that...I did get these warnings:  +-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@^2.3.1
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.8
| +-- minimist@1.2.0
| +-- reflect-metadata@0.1.10
| `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@^2.0.2
`-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/core@^2.3.1

Comment: So, everything is working except for `ng --version`? That is unusual. `ng serve` no problem? Definitely try root. Good luck!

Comment: hmmm, ok, I started over and it worked...I'm thinking the issue was I didn't install with admin, that or the node_modules dir wasn't completely deleted...not sure...thanks for your time...

Comment: Yeah, running it as root is the key. This has bit me in the past. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran through the steps again, this time with cmd opened as admin and everything worked well...not sure what the problem was...

It's also possible I hadn't stopped the server when I ran through it the first time

Answer (score 0):

[**npm start** worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTlJc.jpg)

PS I:\devlab\nipashe-web> ng --version
ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng --version
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS I:\devlab\nipashe-web> npm start

> nipashe-web@0.0.0 start I:\devlab\nipashe-web
>   ng serve

** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200. **
Hash: 9e9c74625fca651c9d2e
Time: 51954ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 153 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 47 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 770 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 387 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 3.48 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Compiled successfully